# Create store and other programatically and after reindex from admin my mysql stop working

Tags: magento-1.9, adminhtml, mysql, programmatically, stores

I am working on my module. I create a store , website and other related information programatically. It is successfully created. But when i reindex data from admin panel my mysql stop working. I don't know what is problem. Let me know how can i solve this problem.

Comment: can you post your mysql error log?

Answer (score 2):

You have to increase your MySQL performances especially if you are working on a development machine.
You can follow websites as it http://astrio.net/blog/magento-performance-optimize-mysql/ to optimize your MySQL config for Magento.
For reindexation prefer with command line : https://www.branded3.com/blog/re-indexing-magento-command-line/

Comment: But why this is happening.

Comment: Your MySQL server has probably gone away, not enough resources to execute all reindexes. If you take a look at logs in `/var/log/exception.log` file you probably see this error.

Comment: My FTP also stop working.

Comment: Technically there is no link between Magento indexes and your FTP. In this case this must be a server issue, not a Magento one. Can you try my first answer, in any case you have to increase MySQL performances.